# Why does SSRS give an rsAccessDenied when trying to view Properties unless user is an administrator on report server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a SQL 2008r2 report server where, despite having the appropriate ROLE permissions assigned within the RS, you can not view a report/folders Properties, unless you are also a member of the administrator group on the server.  You can view the report itself, but not the Properites tab.  When viewing the Properties tab, an rsAccessDenied error is shown with the message "The permissions granted to user 'XXX\XXX' are insufficient for performing this operation."

My understanding is that just being a member of the Browser role should be sufficient to view a reports properties, and the account actually is member of all roles (Content Manager, Publisher, Broweser, etc), so that isn't the issue, so why would you also need to be a member of the administrator group **on the server**?

Given that everything is being done from a browser on a remote computer, I'm at a bit of a loss as to what the Properties tab is doing that requires the extra permissions.

Anyone know what's going on and what needs to be changed so that the user doens't need any permissions on the server itself?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem where I didn't have access to the Properties-tab or the Data Sources-tab but adding my user to Administrators did not solve the issue. However all my role assignments were on a subfolder and when I was added to root/home with role "Browser" it suddenly started working. Even without me being an admin on the RS Server.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft documentation, you need higher privileges to achieve that :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157363(v=sql.105)

Browser role only enables you to navigate through folder structure and view/subscribe to reports.  You need the "Content Manager Role" to achieve what you want.

Comment: The account actually has all roles assigned, and is still unable to view Properties unless the domain account is a member of the Administrators group on the report server.  I'll edit my question to make that clear.